# Angular 5 showing checkboxes as checked based on array

Tags: angular

I have a set of dynamic checkboxes in an Angular form:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let topic of topics">
    <input class="form-check-input" (change)="onChange(f)" #f type="checkbox" [value]="topic.name" name="topicgroup">
    <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: normal">
        {{topic.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

In my edit component, how do I set them as checked?

I have an array that holds all the options, and one which of the options are checked:

```
Topics: string[] = ['Topic1', 'Topic2', 'Topic3', 'Topic4', 'Topic5']; 
selectedTopics: string[] = ['Topic1', 'Topic2'];
```

How do I reflect that on my html page?

Update: This is my onChange function:

```
onChange(f) {
if (this.selectedTopics.indexOf(f.value) == -1) {
  this.selectedTopics.push(f.value);
} else {
  this.selectedTopics.splice(this.selectedTopics.indexOf(f.value), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, You are using `topic.name` as per your array it will be only topic.

Second, Add `[checked]` property to mark them as checked or unchecked as shown below.

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let topic of topics">
    <input class="form-check-input" [checked]="topic in selectedTopics" (change)="onChange(topic)" #f type="checkbox" [value]="topic" name="topicgroup">
    <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: normal">
        {{topic}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Third your `function onChange(topic)` will go as below

```
onChange(topic: string) {
  let index = this.selectedTopics.indexOf(topic);
  if (index == -1) {
    this.selectedTopics.push(value);
  } else {
    this.selectedTopics.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
replace `[checked]="topic in selectedTopics"` with `[checked] = isSelected(topic)`

and in your controller add function

```
isSelected(topic){
    return selectedTopics.indexOf(topic) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: if `[checked]="topic in selectedTopics"` doesnot work you can do `[checked]="selectedTopics.indexof(topic) >= 0"`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these approaches worked.  Either 'unexpected token 'in' ' or "unexpected method 'indexof'

Comment: @RobbieMills I have updated the answer please check it.

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scxyer), you can use `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` to bind your data to the input elements:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let topic of topics; let i=index">
  <input [ngModel]="isSelected(topic)" (ngModelChange)="onChange(topic, $event)" name="topicgroup_{{i}}" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
  <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: normal">
    {{topic}}
  </label>
</div>
```

with the methods `isSelected` and `onChange` defined in the component class:

```
topics: string[] = ['Topic1', 'Topic2', 'Topic3', 'Topic4', 'Topic5'];
selectedTopics: string[] = ['Topic1', 'Topic4'];

isSelected(value: string): boolean {
  return this.selectedTopics.indexOf(value) >= 0;
}

onChange(value: string, checked: boolean) {
  if (checked) {
    this.selectedTopics.push(value);
  } else {
    let index = this.selectedTopics.indexOf(value);
    this.selectedTopics.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

You mention in your question that these controls are to be included in a `form`. Each input element must therefore have a distinct name, which is achieved with the help of the index variable: `name="topicgroup_{{i}}"`.

Comment: @RobbieMills - Was there a problem with my answer? I see that you unmarked it after some part of my code was duplicated in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your datastructure as array of objects with value and checked property

```
selectedTopics: any[] = [ {'value':'Topic1','checked':false}, {'value':'Topic2','checked':true}];
```

whenever checkbox is checked/unchecked you can update the checked property to get the value.

Comment: But selectedTopics is anything that is checked... ?  So I'm not sure how modifying the data will help.  I've updated the question with additional details

Answer (score 0):

Angular varible are case sensitive check this working example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwekdb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That's great, but I'm not sure how it's relevant to my problem